# clash between mathtools and unicode-math

Tags: luatex, incompatibility, unicode-math, mathtools

Lately I started looking into LuaTeX and I must say I’m growing fond of it with every feature I discover. So I decided to transfer my pdfTeX preamble to LuaTex checking which packages still work and which ones need to be replaced.

I use the `mathtools` package with pdfTeX for its `centercolon` and `\smashoperator` features. Unfortunately it seems to clash with the `unicode-math` package under LuaTeX. It boils down to:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\mathtoolsset{centercolon}
\begin{document}
\[:=\coloneq\coloneqq\eqcolon\eqqcolon:=\]
\end{document}
```

results in

```
! Invalid math code.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.5 \mathtoolsset{centercolon}
```

with LuaTex beta-0.70.1 under MiKTeX 2.9. It seems that `unicode-math` is aware of the `mathtools` package as it warns in the log file that some commands were redefined.

---

EDIT: As mentioned above as I’m not working on a true document just doing preamble conversion work. Thus the random choice of Latin Modern Math was a poor one as pointed out by egreg. The partial answer is that the new OpenMath OpenType Fonts make the `centercolon` feature of the `mathtools` package obsolete. I wasn’t aware of that. Of the handfull available OpenMath compliant fonts Neo Euler seems to be the only one where `:=` is not symmetric. I can’t check Minion Math yet. Taking egregs answer into account and avoiding `coloneq` while trying to use `mathtools` to adjust Neo Euler’s `:=` gives however the same error as above:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[version=Asana]{Asana-Math.otf}% Asana Math
\setmathfont[version=Cambria]{Cambria Math}
\setmathfont[version=LatinModern]{Latin Modern Math}
%\setmathfont[version=Minion]{Minion Math}
\setmathfont[version=XITS]{xits-math.otf}% XITS Math
\setmathfont[version=NeoEuler]{Neo Euler}
\begin{document}
\mathversion{Asana} Asana \(:=:=\) 
\mathversion{Cambria} Cambria \(:=:=\) 
\mathversion{LatinModern} LatinModern \(:=:=\) 
\mathversion{XITS} XITS \(:=:=\)
\mathtoolsset{centercolon}
\mathversion{NeoEuler} Neo Euler \(:=:=\)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main problem is that the `\coloneq` character is missing in Latin Modern Math:

```
Missing character: There is no ≔ (U+2254) in font name:LatinModernMath:mode=base;script=math;language=DFLT;!
Missing character: There is no ≔ (U+2254) in font name:LatinModernMath:mode=base;script=math;language=DFLT;!
Missing character: There is no ≕ (U+2255) in font name:LatinModernMath:mode=base;script=math;language=DFLT;!
Missing character: There is no ≕ (U+2255) in font name:LatinModernMath:mode=base;script=math;language=DFLT;!
```

The fact that the messages are repeated is due to `unicode-math` redefining `\coloneqq` to `\coloneq` and `\eqqcolon` to `\eqcolon`.

However, there should be no need to do anything special, since the math mode colon in Latin Modern Math and most other math OpenType fonts *is* symmetrical with respect to the equals sign, so `:=` works as you wish. If you really want to use the control sequences, then

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\coloneq}{:=}%
  \renewcommand{\eqcolon}{=:}%
}
```

is what you need.

For the NeoEuler font, where the colon is not symmetric with respect to `=`, you can emulate the behavior of `mathtools` by writing this code in the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\centercolon}{\mathcode`:="8000 }
\begingroup\catcode`\~=\active \lccode`~=`:
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\mathrel{\mathop\normalcolonchar}}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \edef\normalcolonchar{\Umathcharnum\the\Umathcodenum`: }
  \edef\normalcolon{\Umathcodenum`:=\the\Umathcodenum`: }
}
```

Then the declaration `\centercolon` will center the colon with respect to the math axis, from that point on; the declaration `\normalcolon` is the opposite (so `\centercolon` is similar to `\mathtoolsset{centercolon}`).

[image]

Comment: I’d like to know where the “missing character” log entries are from? If I look into LuaTeX’s `Transcript written on test.log.` I cannot find them there. If I remove `\coloneq` and the other macros from the MWE and just use `\[:=:=\]` I still get the same errors. As I’m only working on the preamble and not on a true document Latin Modern Math was just an unfortunated random pick it seems. From the few available OpenMath OpenType Fonts Neo Euler seems to be the only one to have a non-symmetrical `:=`.

Comment: I find those entries in the log file. My version of Latin Modern Math is 0.903. Please, update your question to reflect the real problem.

Comment: I have the same version here. Is there something like `loglevel=debug` that makes the log more verbose?

Comment: Try adding `\tracinglostchars=2` after `\begin{document}`

Comment: `\tracinglostchars` has no effect, probably due to [this bug](http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=709)